# Google Apps Script I want to add all users in an organization to a group

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-developer-tools

Using Google Apps Script I want to add all users in an organization to a group. If possible, it would be great if it also takes users in its sub-organization. I am waiting for your help in this matter. I also care about your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a code you're working on? What research did you do till now? Please take into account that your question is very broad, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I can provide a broad description and explanation of the necessary steps, but not the full code you'd need. If that's ok for you, I'll post an answer with this.

Comment: Hello there,
There is no code that I am working on right now. I have been searching for a long time, but I could not get any results on the subject. Actually, I am not a full judge. I have a student OU I want, I want to add all users under this OU to the group with the help of Apps Script.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to do even without Apps Script. Take a look at [this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9689259?hl=en).

You can also achieve the same programmatically by using the Google [Workspace Admin API](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10427204?hl=en).

Comment: I could not explain my problem. I just want to add all users in x / y / a ou to a group. I want to use Apps Script to do this automatically.

Comment: Call the Workspace Admin API from your apps script. Make sure the authenticated user has rights to create Google groups and read OUs

Answer (score 0):

No turn is what I want. I want to add a student ONU all users to a group. I want to do this with apps script in this process. Actually very understandable